# How to convert list into array in a function - python?

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy

I defined a function(procedure) to read a file. I want it returns arrays with data I want to read from the file, as it follows:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Subroutine to read the day, Ta,Tp from a file and convert them into arrays
def readstr(fname,day,Ta,Tp):
    van = open(fname,'r')
    van_csv = van.readlines()[7:] # Skip seven lines
    van.close()                   # close the file
    van_csv = csv.reader(van_csv) # now the file is separated by colunms 
    for row  in van_csv: # Passing the values of the each column to arrays
      day.append(row[1])
      Ta.append(row[8])
      Tp.append(row[7])
    day = np.array(day,dtype=np.integer)
    Ta = np.array(Ta,dtype=np.float)
    Tp = np.array(Tp,dtype=np.float)
van = "file"
# Defining the lists
dayVan = []
Tav = []
Tpv = []

readstr(van,dayVan,Tav,Tpv)
print Tav
```

I thought it would  work, but dayVan, Tpv, Tav keep being lists.

Comment: you are not modifying `Ta (Tav)` and `Tp (Tpv)`. You are binding a new instance that is returned by `np.array` to `Ta` and `Tp`. This means you are replacing the `Tav` binding with a new binding, yet `Tav` keeps being bound to an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Ta = np.array(Ta,dtype=np.float)
```

Creates a *new* array object from the contents of the list `Ta`, it then assigns this array to the **local** identifier `Ta`. It does **not** change the global that references the list.

Python doesn't have "variables". It has identifiers. When doing `a = b` you simply say "bind the name `a` to the object bound to `b`". The `a` is simply a label that can be used to retrieve an object. If you then do `a = 0` you are re-binding the label `a` but this does **not** affect the object bound to `b`. The identifiers are **not** memory locations.

To pass the resulting arrays out of the function you can:

- Return them and re-assign the global `Ta`.
- Assign directly to the global variable. However in order to do this the local `Ta` should be given a new name *and* you'd have to use the `global` statement(Note: *avoid* this solution.)

Comment: Than you for the explanation.

Comment: See also the other replies, for you can see a very interesting short way of reading the file and and how the first suggestion can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can simply do:

```
dayVan, Tpv, Tav = np.loadtxt(fname, usecols=(1,7,8), skiprows=7, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Comment: It does not work because the file is a rather complex: the first seven lines are "trash"(output of a program), the next lines are well-formatted (columns separated by commas). I tried to skip rows, but it is not working yet. The following error:  "File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 827, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2,"

Comment: @Marcos that's interesting, maybe you could provide a sample of your file in an external link do that I can have a look...

Comment: @Marcos just do: `np.loadtxt('stack.txt', skiprows=7, usecols=(1,7,8), delimiter=',')`

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is correctly done, but only inside your function.

Try to return day, Ta and Tp at the end of your function, and get them from the caller, it will work better.

```
def readstr(fname):
    van = open(fname,'r')
    van_csv = van.readlines()[7:] # Skip seven lines
    van.close()                   # close the file
    van_csv = csv.reader(van_csv) # now the file is separated by colunms 
    day, Ta, Tp = [], [], []
    for row  in van_csv: # Passing the values of the each column to arrays
      day.append(row[1])
      Ta.append(row[8])
      Tp.append(row[7])
    day = np.array(day,dtype=np.integer)
    Ta = np.array(Ta,dtype=np.float)
    Tp = np.array(Tp,dtype=np.float)
    return day, Ta, Tp

dayVan, Tav, Tpv = readstr(van)
```

Comment: It perfectly works, as it was suggested by Bakuriu. Thanks for rewriting my script in the correct form.